# VBA: How can I make my function work for both vertical and horizontal vector

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, function, vector

I have a vector (both row and column) and I want to calculate a specific function (e.g. x+5) for each value in that vector and I want to have it displayed in the specified array of cells. I wrote a function and in Excel it works for a single cell or for row vector. But when I try it on column vector it returns the value computed for the first cell for all values in the array. Can you please help me, what I did wrong or why it is not working?
My code lookd like this

Option Base 1

```
Public Function TestFunction(arr As Range) As Variant
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim j As Integer
 Dim NoCols As Integer
 Dim NoRws As Integer
 Dim FV() As Double

 NoCols = arr.Columns.Count
 NoRws = arr.Rows.Count


If NoCols = 1 Then
  ReDim FV(NoRws)
     For i = 1 To NoRws
         x = arr.Rows(i)
         FV(i) = x + 5
    Next i

Else
 ReDim FV(NoCols)
    For j = 1 To NoCols
     y = arr.Columns(j)
     FV(j) = y + 5
    Next j

End If

TestFunction = FV()

End Function
```

Comment: what is `FX` in your code, did you mean to have `FV` instead

Comment: You ReDim FX but declare and return FV.  I don't see how it would work in either case like that.  Is this code an exact copy of your working code?

Comment: yes, I meant FV, just typing mistake. I've already corrected it.  in my original code it's the same and it's not working

Comment: Your presumption is wrong. It works the same kind also for column vectors. But it returns a row vector in both cases. Shall it return a row vector if a row vector is given and a column vector if a column vector is given?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it shall it return a row vector if a row vector is given and a column vector if a column vector is given. If so then:

```
Public Function TestFunction(arr As Range) As Variant
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim j As Integer
 Dim NoCols As Integer
 Dim NoRws As Integer
 Dim FV() As Double

 NoCols = arr.Columns.Count
 NoRws = arr.Rows.Count

 If NoCols = 1 Then
  ReDim FV(1 To NoRws, 1 To 1) ' column vector = multiple rows, 1 column = FV(row, 1), using (1 to ...) DIMs to avoid Option Base 1
  For i = 1 To NoRws
   x = arr.Cells(i, 1)
   FV(i, 1) = x + 5
  Next i
 ElseIf NoRws = 1 Then
  ReDim FV(1 To 1, 1 To NoCols) ' row vector = 1 row, multiple columns = FV(1, column)
  For j = 1 To NoCols
   y = arr.Cells(1, j)
   FV(1, j) = y + 5
  Next j
 End If

 TestFunction = FV()

End Function
```

Comment: thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed. I have a question though...why would I want to avoid using "Option Base 1"? is it just to have a one line less in the code or can it cause any problems?

Comment: This is simply my convention because i can not rely on Option Base. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266179%28v=vs.60%29.aspx : "Option Base does not affect ParamArray (or the Array function, when qualified with the name of its type library, for example VBA.Array)". And Objects from outside the module will also not being affected. So in my opinion it is better to declare the LBound directly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't fight against using **two dimensional** arrays.

This will work for a single row or a single column or a block of cells:

```
Option Base 1

Public Function TestFunction(arr As Range) As Variant
   Dim i As Long
   Dim j As Long
   Dim NoCols As Long
   Dim NoRws As Long
   Dim FV()

   NoCols = arr.Columns.Count
   NoRws = arr.Rows.Count
   FV = arr

   For i = 1 To NoRws
      For j = 1 To NoCols
         FV(i, j) = FV(i, j) + 5
      Next j
   Next i

   TestFunction = FV()

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: In this special case your solution is better. But you also working with a two dimensional array. And one should know how those kind of arrays work. What if it explicit shall not work with a block of cells? And/Or if the function for row vectors is different from the function for column vectors?

Comment: @AxelRichter  You are correct..............special cases WOULD require special approaches..............for the posted example of adding **5** to an arbitrary array, my approach will work whether the input is a single row or a single column or a simple block of cells.  **The function cells must be inserted in an arrangement that is isomorphic to the input arrangement.**